# Xpath for Submit button with precedence nodes select file and *

Tags: selenium, xpath

**Query 1:**

I would request you to please help me on getting xpath for submit button. Absolute path starts with Select file and *.

```
<div id="bg">

      <label id="label" style=" font-family: Segoe UI;color:#2e2e2e; font-size:12px; float:left; padding-top:8px;">

            Select File <span id="spanhide" class="red">*</span></label>

           <div style="margin-left:105px;"><input type="file" name="filUploadIcon" id="filUploadIcon" class="txt-box" onchange="FileUpload_OnChange(this,event);" style="width:180px;">

            <input type="submit" name="btnUploadcancel" value="" onclick="return check();" id="btnUploadcancel" title="Upload" class="upload_pop"></div>              

            <input name="textFileName" type="text" id="textFileName" style="display:none;">        



             <input type="hidden" name="hdnframeID" id="hdnframeID">

             <input type="hidden" name="hdnlbl" id="hdnlbl">

    </div>
```

**Query 2:**

How to write xpath to skip few nodes in between. Please help. Also let me know adding `//` or `*` in between to skip nodes.

```
Ex: Above HTML

//*div[@id="bg"]/skip elements before input type submit node/input [@type="submit"]
```

Comment: the questions are not clear. What are trying to do with submit button.? are you trying to upload a file to a target?

Comment: Thanks for your suppport. I am trying to upload a file. But the page has 2 select files fields. Both were having same html. But the only difference is second instance has asterisk in that. Could you please help me in getting xpath.is there any shortcut for multiple same fields in xpath. Ex. Third instance this xpath if there were 5 fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below xpath to target the precedence nodes that include the `label` with the string "Select File" and the embedded `span` that contains '*'.

```
//div[contains(@id, 'bg')]/label[contains(text(), 'Select File')]/span[contains(text(), '*')]
```

Then add on the below line to return to the parent node `label` to the `span` tag.

```
/parent::label
```

Then add on the below to get to the sibling `div` tag of the `label` tag, which contains the `input` tag with a type of submit.

```
/following-sibling::div/input[@type='submit']
```

So the xpath in its entirety should look like this:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'bg')]/label[contains(text(), 'Select File')]/span[contains(text(), '*')]/parent::label/following-sibling::div/input[@type='submit']
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Challenge faced is page has 2. Select file fields. Both were having same html. But the only difference is second instance has asterisk in that. Could you please help me in getting xpath.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understood you the first time. I edited the answer to match up to what I think you're looking for.
If you need to get the xpath for the submit button using the precedence nodes containing 'Select File' and '*', then this should work

Comment: No Sorry please. Thanks for a lot for your kind help. You are great and rocked.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful, consider marking it up ;)

Comment: Already voted. But got message votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Thanks again for your kindness

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about that. Never mind then. And you're most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use below xpath.

```
//div[@id='bg']//input[@name='btnUploadcancel']
```

Strongly suggest to go through [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) to learn more on xpath 1.0 which will answer all your questions in OP.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Challenge faced is page has 2. Select file fields. Both were having same html. But the only difference is second instance has asterisk in that. Could you please help me in getting xpath. Thanks a lot for your guidance on xpath learning